# C# Problem with Receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets

When I send data from the client side many times one after another very quickly, i don't receive these data separately in the server. I receive them as one large data burst. I need send the reply for every received data . But i can't do it, because these data join in one large burst. How can I send reply for every received data?
 Here the code of callback method in the server:

```
    private void RecieveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        ConnectionInfo connection = (ConnectionInfo)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = connection.Socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                    connection.FullBufferReceive.Add(connection.BufferReceive[i]);
                if (bytesRead == connection.BufferReceive.Length)
                {
                    connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.BufferReceive, 0, connection.BufferReceive.Length, 0,
                                                   new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), connection);
                    Console.WriteLine("Bytes recieved -- " + bytesRead + " by " + connection.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bytes recieved " + bytesRead + " by " + connection.Id);

                    _serverController.StartProcess(connection);
                }
            }
            else  
                CloseConnection(connection);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CloseConnection(connection);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: and the question is? please describe the question ;)

Comment: The client code will probably be more useful.  Perhaps you need to call `.Flush()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your sockets are TCP (I can't tell from the code), this is expected behavior as TCP isn't framed like UDP is.  You need to delimit the data yourself.

Comment: +1, Also when using UDP your message could be split if one of the network hops think it's too big.

Comment: ok, so what this means is: when you do a "send" on your client of X bytes, and a read on your server, don't expect X bytes back.  You need to keep reading until either you find a delimiter that your protocol prescribes (like a newline - another option is to first send the length of the data to read in some encoding, and then send the data and keep reading until you read that much).  Good luck!